# SQL: only querying results that have two rows in a second table associated to them

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm relatively new to SQL so the following might be a simple question. I've been trying to write a query that only returns names that have two specific types of addresses associated with them. There is a name table and an address table. It's in a MYSQL server.

```
    customer
| id |  name       |
|  1 | john smith  |
|  2 | bob vance   |
|  3 | jane doe    |
|  4 | doug smith  |


                           address
| id |    type   |      street      |   state   |  name_id  |
|  1 |    home   | 123 main street  |     NJ    |     3     |
|  2 |  business | 100 south lane   |     NY    |     3     |
|  3 |    home   | 75 boardwalk way |     CT    |     1     |
|  4 |    home   |  3 cherry lane   |     NY    |     2     |
|  5 |    home   |   15 south way   |     NY    |     4     |
|  6 |  business |   90 west end    |     NY    |     4     |
```

I would like to return names who have both a home and business address, demonstrated in the results below.

```
| name     |  type        |    street       |   state   |
| jane doe |    home      | 123 main street |     NJ    |
| jane doe |   business   | 100 south lane  |     NY    |
|doug smith|   home       |  15 south way   |     NY    |
|doug smith|  business    |  90 west end    |     NY    |
```

I am able to join the tables together, however I am having difficulty filtering in this manner. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE name_id IN (SELECT name_id
                  FROM address
                  WHERE type IN ('home', 'business')
                  GROUP BY name_id
                  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(type)) = 2)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be63a/1

Comment: You beat me to it, but your answer is better than what I was working on.

Comment: OP says he needs home and business, so you should add `WHERE type in ('home', 'business')`

Comment: @paul I just read the question again, and yes, very good point.

Comment: @X-Zero Yes, exactly two of two types, which is perfect. It requires they have both because of the `DISTINCT`. Notice all three of Jane Doe's addresses show up and Bob Vance still does not in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bbdfa/1